# Pour quelle raison « il me court sur le haricot » ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison

Dans le contexte des élections de ce dimanche, en parlant avec des amis au téléphone, l'un d'entre eux m'a rétorqué en parlant d'un des candidats : *Il me court sur le haricot*.

J'ai déjà entendu cette expression un bon nombre de fois, et l'ai déjà utilisée moi-même, mais je profite d'être membre de ce site pour vous poser la question : quelle est l'origine de cette expression, et pourquoi un *haricot* plutôt qu'autre chose ?

Comment: Effectivement, « il me court » aurait le même sens, donc pourquoi le haricot plutôt qu'autre chose ? En cherchant sur Google, je vois une idée reprise sur plusieurs sites que le *haricot* serait ici l'orteil, ce qui me laisse dubitatif : pourquoi le singulier, alors ? Et pourquoi l'orteil ? Je soupçonnerais plutôt haricot dans le sense de graine, donc tête, mais je n'ai aucun argument pour substancier cette conjecture.

Comment: Est-ce qu'on ne dit pas aussi *courir sur le système*? Je ne sais pas quelle expression précède l'autre, par contre.

Comment: @Circeus: je crois qu'on tape plus qu'on ne court sur le système.

Comment: Je soupçonne que "courir sur le haricot" et "courir sur le paillasson" sont bien plus grossières que "marcher sur les pieds" ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey).

« Haricot » au sens argotique désigne l'orteil (apparu fin du 19è siècle) et par synecdoque le pied.  D'où *courir sur le haricot/le pied*.

À noter aussi les expressions *peler le haricot* et *taper sur le haricot* employées aussi pour signifier *ennuyer*, *importuner*. Alain Rey signale que :

> « haricot » a pu signifier « testicule » comme l'atteste *haricocèle*
>   nom masculin, « testicule atrophié », 1907.

Comment: J'aimerais savoir d'où Alain Rey tire son interprétation du sens de haricot ici. On pèle plus le jonc que le haricot, ce n'est assurément pas l'orteil (ni le pied). Et quand on tape, ce n'est pas non plus sur l'orteil.

Comment: @Gilles: l'emploi de *a pu* suggère qu'Alain Rey fait **une spéculation** sur le sens de *haricot* fondée sur la pathologie du haricocèle. Passer de ce sens de *testicule atrophié* à *jonc* il n'y a qu'un pas à faire.  *Il me pèle le jonc* est une expression courante et effectivement une recherche sur google montre que *peler le haricot* et *taper le haricot* sont aussi employées.

Answer (score 2):

[Extrait dut *reverso* définition française :](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/courir%20sur%20le%20haricot)

> D'un côté, nous avons le verbe 'courir' (quelqu'un) qui, dans cet emploi populaire et transitif, signifie déjà tout seul **'importuner'** dès le XVIe siècle.
>   D'un autre, nous avons le verbe **'haricoter'** qui, au début du XIXe, signifie soit "être mesquin en affaires", soit "marchander sur des riens" (ce qui exaspère, forcément), ou bien encore "importuner".

Le  *clitoris* est aussi nommé *haricot* en argot (une recherche sur ces deux mots fournira toutes les précisions désirées), il n'est donc pas difficile de comprendre l'énervement que procure une stimulation non désirée.

Comment: Étrange que cette expression soit *unisexe* dans son usage.

Comment: @Knu Disons qu'il est blanc pour les dames et vert pour les messieurs, plus pour les proportions que pour les mensurations (Henri IV n'était-il pas appelé le vert galant)