# Comment traduire l'expression « get on your tits » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Je cherche à traduire la phrase :

> that must really get on your tits!

Je pense comprendre le sens général : quelque chose d'ennuyeux, dans le sens de légèrement dérangeant...
Mais je ne trouve pas d'équivalent en Français, dans un **langage familier**.

D'avance merci si vous avez des pistes !

Comment: Where did you see or find that? It is not a usual thing but one can make stuff up. Like this.

Comment: *Get on your tits* is not common in English either, as I've not heard it much; perhaps once or twice. But it's like *Get on your nerves*. I have heard *Cool your tits* as in *Calm down*

Comment: @Lambie Not that common but well ingrained in English slang, absolutely not "made up" by one obscure individual.  You can read the definition in the OED: "to get on one’s tits or (occas.) tit: to irritate intensely, get on the nerves of. slang."  followed by various quotes, oldest one 1945. It is in the *Partridge New dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*.

Comment: @Well ingrained? Then, it would be common. Anyway, it's vulgar so it can't just be taper sur les nerfs.

Comment: @Lambie I found this sentence in a little text a friend of mine wrote. He wanted me to translate it in French. He is Welsh, maybe this expression is more common in Wales ?

Comment: @Polosson Perhaps, I have no idea. But it's vulgar.

Comment: To keep on the vulgar tone, I'd said in vulgar slang French "ça doit te casser les couilles !" (translate to 'This must be breaking your balls' according to [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/couilles/)) (and you can see we have a pretty number of expression around testes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tu n'as pas peur d'avoir l'air un peu ringard tu peux utiliser l'expression "courir sur le haricot" (lit: to run on the bean). Le "haricot" en question représente une partie du corps sur laquelle serait en train de courir une petite bête, et ça commence à gratter. Pour l'instant c'est encore supportable, mais la si ça ne s'arrête pas on risque d'atteindre un stade de colère supérieur. Cas d'usage commun:

> Tes mensonges commencent à me courir sur le haricot, dis-moi la vérité maintenant ou je vais m'énerver !

Moins ringard mais très similaire: "taper sur les nerfs". En général c'est un désagrément plus fort que "courir sur le haricot".

Sinon il y a l'éternel "faire chier" qui est vulgaire et peu précis. Cela peut désigner l'ennui, le désagrément léger, le désagrément lourd, la catastrophe imprévue...

Comment: taper sur les nerfs n'est pas vulgaire du tout. La phrase donnée est même très vulgaire. To get on someone's tits is a deformation of to get on someone's nerves. And it doesn't really exist per se. Someone just made it up. Taper sur les nichons, aussi n'existe pas mais donne l'idée de vulgarité inventée au hazard.

Comment: @Lambie *Le haricot* a au moins le même niveau de vulgarité que *tits*,  en commun avec l'expression anglaise, la référence à une partie du corps, la relative basse fréquence d'emploi de ces expressions, le fait que le mot se retrouve dans diverses expressions, (courir sur  / taper sur / *on your tits / off your tits/* ...).  [Pour quelle raison « il me court sur le haricot » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2521/358). *Ciboulot* (taper sur / courir sur /) aurait était une bonne alternative mais moins cru que *haricot*.

Comment: Parmi ces propositions, seule « faire chier » est une traduction acceptable. Les autres sont beaucoup trop polies.

Answer (score 4):

Comme relevé dans d'autres réponses, la phrase d'origine est elle-même une variation d'un idiome plus courant, *to get on one's nerves*, qui a une traduction littérale en français : *taper sur les nerfs*. La variation indique d'une part que le locuteur est une femme en mentionnant les seins et d'autre part utilise un registre de langage plus familier en se référant aux seins par le terme *tits*.

En recherchant les équivalents familiers de *taper sur les nerfs*, on trouve *courir sur le haricot* et *casser / briser les couilles*, ce dernier terme étant parfois, en fonction de l'effet recherché, remplacé par un euphémisme comme *les noix* ou *les bonbons*, voire simplement sous-entendu comme dans *me les briser*.

Mais toutes ces expressions ci-dessus sous-entendent, pour ma part, un locuteur mâle.

Je suggérerais donc la variation suivante :

> Ça a dû te briser les miches

*Miche* étant un mot d'argot pouvant designer à la fois les seins de la femme ou les fesses.

Une autre possibilité moins imagée est

> Ça a dû te saouler
>
> Ça a dû te gonfler

Comment: Je suis du Québec, je ne partage donc pas toute les mêmes expressions qu'en France; j'ai toujours cru que les miches disignaient les fesses, est-ce aussi le cas?

Comment: @AlexDupuis Je vis en France et pour moi *miches* désignent aussi les fesses. La signification est peut-être régionale... En tout cas dans la série *Kaamelott* ça veut bien dire fesses :)

Comment: Je vais amender la réponse. Miche signifie bien fesses en effet mais peut aussi vouloir dire seins. Il y a une source qui prétend que ça peut vouloir dire testicules aussi mais comme je n'en trouve pas d'autre ça vaut le coup de l'enlever. Pour seins ils y a plusieurs attestations comme https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/miches

Comment: [_Ton Antoine commence à me les briser menu !_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQVu1n_boec)

Answer (score 3):

Cette expression ressemble énormément à une autre : *getting on one's nerves*,
qui indique l'agacement. On peut donc traduire ta phrase par

> Ça a vraiment dû t'agacer/t'énerver/t'irriter

ou toute autre expression exprimant cette idée.

*Getting on one's tits* est une variante féminine de cette expression (*tits* désignant les seins). La traduction reste donc la même.

**Edit important** : J'ai sauté la phrase où tu demandes un langage familier on dirait, au temps pour moi.

Mais si tu prends en compte le reste de ma réponse, tu pourras en conclure que l'expression *taper sur les nerfs* proposée par AnneAunyme est la meilleure et plus proche traduction possible

Comment: Toutes ces propositions sont beaucoup trop polies.

Answer (score 0):

Taper sur les nerfs, me les briser, me les briser menu, me chatouiller, m'escagacer (Provencal), m'emmerder...

Comment: *Escagaçar* en provençal mais *escaga**ss**er* en français (pas de lien avec *agacer*).